# React: Reference of element with Logical AND (&&)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use `useRef` hook to get a reference of an element, the problem here is that the `current` object in ref got value of `undefined`, Why? **because I use logical AND `isTrue && (JSX)`**, see it:

###### Video.jsx

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import photo from '../../../Assets/browse.jpg'
import PopupPreview from './PopupPreview'

function VideoItem() {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState(false)
  const videoRef = useRef()

  const handleEnterVeiw = (e) => {
    const target = e.currentTarget
    const targetPositions = target.getBoundingClientRect()
    console.log(targetPositions.top)
    console.log(targetPositions.right)
    console.log(targetPositions.bottom)
    console.log(targetPositions.left)

    setVideo(true)
    console.log(viedoRef)
  }
  const handleLeaveVeiw = (e) => {
    setVideo(false)
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        className='SLider__Item'
        onMouseEnter={handleEnterVeiw}
        onMouseLeave={handleLeaveVeiw}
      >
        <div
          className='bg-img-co'
          onClick={() => alert('You Clicked on the img')}
        >
          <img src={photo} alt='' />
        </div>

        // Here is the trick
        {video &&
          ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <PopupPreview ref={videoRef}/>,
            document.getElementById('pop-up-preview')
          )}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default VideoItem
```

###### PopupPreview.jsx

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'
import YouTube from 'react-youtube'

import '../../../Styles/Browse/pop-up-preview.css'
const PopupPreview = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => alert('You Clicked on the video')}
      className='pop-up-info'
      ref={ref}
    >
      <YouTube
        onReady={() => console.log('Ready to play')}
        onPlay={() => console.log('is played')}
        className='Video__Container'
        iframeClassName='Video'
        videoId='XtMThy8QKqU'
        onError={(e) => {
          console.log(e)
        }}
        opts={{
          width: 190,
          height: 107,
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 0,
            mute: 1,
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
})
export default PopupPreview
```

[That is what logging in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unvOA.png)

I want reference of element to give it `target`'s dimensions

when the mouse hover on the element the ref logging in console as `{current: undefined}`, What's the solution to get the correct reference without any bug?

Comment: You are not changing the value anywhere, why should it change?

Comment: I don't know! Wait Iam going to put a picture for the console output

Comment: You never use `viedoRef`

Comment: @Konrad It's value `undefined`, Sorry for that

Comment: @Konrad I made edits to code, Sorry again

Comment: Works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-flower-5x69t8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access the variable before it has been filled with the newly rendered component.

If you check in a `useEffect` you will have access to it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(videoRef.current);
}, [video]);
```

Demo at: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-poitras-nml1kb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's not working, in `VideoItem` component it repeated several times because I put it on slider, so with every render each one logging the value on console, up to 999 logging on first render